# How to close the fiscal year accounts in odoo 11

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

I would like to know how to close the fiscal year accounts and create a opening balance for current year in odoo 11.

Comment: In Odoo close the fiscal year in 31st December, so here your opening balance automatic carry to next year.